# Github actions, pip and PATH

Tags: github, pip, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to use a package installed with pip in Github Actions workflow. [In the documentation, I found a code example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/building-and-testing-python#starting-with-the-python-workflow-template) which doing something similar to what I want:

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
```

but I a try to use run the workflow I see an error below:

> ```
> /home/runner/work/_temp/cd52f069-5af0-49d4-832f-b750b17fdb7a.sh: line 2: flake8: command not found
> Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
> ```

How should I modify a code sample to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried `python -m flake8 <...>`?